# Is it possible to send messages through Microsoft Teams from Excel Macros?

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-teams

I used to send a lot of emails through Outlook form Excel Macros, but now I need to send everyday a message in a group chat of Teams every 2 hours (with the results of a report), so I would like to know if it is possible to automate, including "@" to mention some coworkers.

Regards

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I have no idea, but hope someone who has the knowledge to give some idea or direction.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-an-email-to-a-channel-in-teams-d91db004-d9d7-4a47-82e6-fb1b16dfd51e

Comment: @Maurito, Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: Hi. The link provided by @Tim Williams looks useful; I'll answer back once I try it

Comment: @Maurito, Does that help provided by Tim Williams useful. Are you able to send messages.

Comment: @Sridevi-MSFT Yes, it was helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: A simpler way to achieve this may be with Flow - see https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/excel-bpf-todo-and-more/

Answer (score -3):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Tim Williams comments

You can send messages to teams channel using the channel email address. You can get channel email address by going to channel name. Check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-an-email-to-a-channel-in-teams-d91db004-d9d7-4a47-82e6-fb1b16dfd51e) for more details.